# Angular 2 Disabled Required Control is invalid

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2 Reactive Form. I have a form Control which is defined with required validation.
When the user loads the form and this control is populated Angular consider the form control as valid. (Which is good!)

However, if the form control is populated and it's also disabled angular consider it as invalid? (W-H-Y?)

Have anyone encountered this? Is this a bug or by design?

Thanks!

Comment: `if the form control is populated and it's also disabled angular consider it as invalid`-------what does this line even mean?

Comment: I don't understand this, if you are using reactive forms, disabling a field should exclude the form field from the form entirely, therefore it doesn't matter if there is validation or not, it won't be looked at. There should therefore not be a problem at all. Could you please provide a plunker? :)

Answer (score 7):

This is by design, as per the [W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled) disabled inputs are not valid. In Angular you can use [`FormGroup.getRawValues()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#getRawValue-anchor) if you want to retrieve all values regardless of whether they are disabled or not.

Alternatively consider using the `readonly` attr instead.